# Add, edit specific CPT with custom role

Tags: theme-development, user-roles, capabilities

Who can help me with roles and capabilities?
I am stuck on this and I need some help.

I want a role that only can add, remove edit etc. a specific CPT.

What I have so far

```
add_action('init', function(){  
    register_post_type( 'catalog',
        array(
            'capability_type'   => 'manage_catalog',
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => 'Catalogus',
                'add_new'       => 'Nieuw item',
                'add_new_item'  => 'Nieuw item toevoegen',
                'new_item'      => 'Nieuw item',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => false,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-store',
            'menu_position' => 2,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail',
            ),
        )
    );

add_action('load-themes.php', function(){
    global $pagenow;

    if('themes.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['activated'])){ 
        $role = get_role('subscriber');
        $role->add_cap('manage_catalog'); 
    }else{
        //Remove the capacity when theme is deactivate
        $role = get_role('subscriber');
        $role->remove_cap('manage_catalog');
    }
});
```

With the code above I can not see the CPT catalog in the menu on the admin side.
What I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such hook named *load-themes.php* in WordPress. One of the hooks you can use to add custom capabilities is *after_setup_theme*.

Also, there's no need to use `'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['activated'])` condition there. What are you trying to achieve this way?

Try to use this code instead:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
  $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );

  $singular = 'catalog';
  $plural = 'catalogs';

  $role->add_cap( "edit_{$singular}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "edit_{$plural}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "edit_others_{$plural}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "publish_{$plural}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "read_{$singular}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "read_private_{$plural}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "delete_{$singular}" ); 
  $role->add_cap( "delete_{$plural}" );
  $role->add_cap( "delete_private_{$plural}" );
  $role->add_cap( "delete_others_{$plural}" );
  $role->add_cap( "edit_published_{$plural}" );
  $role->add_cap( "edit_private_{$plural}" );
  $role->add_cap( "delete_published_{$plural}" );
} );
```